# Increase in the load capacity FET output (pin.8) SMSC EMC2112 chip

Tags: circuit-design

There is an [RPM-Based Linear Fan Controller with Hardware Thermal Shutdown](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/2112.pdf) which has the ability to set the output pin.8 to a low state when certain events occur, which can serve as a system shutdown signal.

The load capacity of the internal FET not defined in the datasheet, but it is for sure less than 1A, which is necessary for me to use the state of this pin. 8 to turn on some load.

I am a programmer and have only basic knowledge in electronics, so I assume that the required flowchart would have to look something like this…
[image]

I need help clarifying the circuit, choosing a FET driver and an external FET.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re not switching at high speed then you can get away without a FET driver.  You’ll need to find a FET with a low enough gate threshold that it can readily pass the required current with 3.3V at the gate.  Here’s an example:

https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMN6075S.pdf

You can see from the graphs that with 3.0V on the gate, the device can pass at least 2A which should be ample for your application.  There are many other FETs that will do the job.

Comment: If the load is inductive ( eg a relay coil) then you’ll need a ‘freewheel’ diode, which has its anode on the low side of the load and cathode on the high (5V) side.  This stops the load from generating a large voltage spike when it’s turned off.

Comment: Hi, Frog. Thanks for the detailed answer. I would like to clarify that I want the external FET to open on a transition from a high to a low state of pin. 8 EMC2112 chip. If my train of thought is correct - that's why I suggested using the FET driver MCP1415  https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/2112.pdf since it has an inverted output. Kindly, comment on the course of my thoughts, whether the scheme is redundant. Is it possible to simplify the circuit even more? TIA.

Comment: In that case your proposed solution is a valid one.  The driver is a $1 part in one-off, so if you’re interested in simplicity then it’s a good choice but if you’re more interested in BOM cost then a simple inverter using a FET and pull-up would be a cheaper option.

Comment: Hi, Frog. Thanks for the detailed answer, but I'm afraid that with my knowledge in the field of electronics, I can hardly understand the second part of your answer correctly. Could you please provide a specific, proposed scheme with a minimum BOM, at least hand-drawn. TIA.

Comment: I’m away from home at the moment and have only my phone, so I’ll stick to a written description, perhaps another contributor can draw a sketch.  Find a general-purpose FET such as a 2N7002, connect the gate to the EMC2112.  Connect the source to GND and the drain via a 10k resistor to 5V.  What happens here is that a ‘high’ output from the EMC2112 allows the FET to conduct between drain and source, so the drain is pulled down to GND.  Conversely, when the EMC2112 outputs a low voltage the FET does not allow current to flow, so the resistor pulls the drain high.

Comment: Finally, connect the gate of the second FET (eg DMN6075) to the drain of the first FET.  Now the first FET and resistor are inverting the signal and the second FET is passing the current from the load.  Hope that helps.